# Translating a world position to an array position

Tags: unity, c#, vector, data-structure

Lets keep this simple, so, assuming I have an array like this ...

```
var array = new bool[10,10,10];
```

.. and then I have a start and end vector3 ...

```
var start = new Vector3(-21,-21,-21);
var end = new Vector3(-10,-10,-10);
```

... these booleans represent some data for a part of my virtual world, but they are a small chunk of that data between the start and end points in the world.

How do I, given a point in the virtual world translate that position to a point in the array ...

```
var pos = new Vector3(-20,-20,-20);

var result = GetValueAt(pos);

bool GetValueAt(Vector3 pos)
{
    // my question is:
    //what goes in here to translate from pos to array pos [1,1,1] ?
   return array[1,1,1];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract the start-vector from the position-vector and you get the array indices.

```
bool GetValueAt(Vector3 pos)
{
   return array[pos.x - start.x, pos.y - start.y, pos.z - start.z ];
}
```

You might also want to add some error-checking in case the caller provides a position outside of the array.

Also, this code assumes that all three coordinates of `start` are smaller than those of `end`. When that is not always the case, you need to find the smaller value on each axis and subtract that one from the corresponding axis of `pos`.

Answer (score -3):

```
var pos = new Vector3(-20,-20,-20);

var result = GetValueAt(pos);

bool GetValueAt(Vector3 pos)
{
   return array[pos.x, pos.y, pos.z];
}
```

You can just pull the coords out separately.

Comment: This won't work. You can't access an array with indices of -20, -20 and -20. Those are not valid indices, it's outside the bounds of the array.